# How can I root the Posh Mobile Orion Pro x500A?

Tags: rooting

I recently bought a Posh Mobile Orion Pro (x500A running 4.4.2) as a new phone. It has good bones and I've been looking for methods of rooting to remove bloatware and to optimize some of the performance (battery and internal storage partition, in particular).

I've looked and looked but I can't seem to find a specific rooting method for this phone. [One Click Root](http://www.oneclickroot.com/rootable/) says there's no root available for this phone, but I don't know if that means it *can't* be rooted at all, or if there's no specific method for this particular device.

I'm interested in CWM or Cyanogenmod. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you already have a possibility to get into recovery and flash a .zip file in there? If you can, then you should be able to flash SuperSU onto your device (Easy to find on Google). Otherwise, you'd have to check how to flash CWM or TWRP through fastboot mode. I don't know if _any_ CWM image would work though :/

Comment: This device has mt6582 chipset which means it can be flashed using [SP Flash Tools](http://androidxda.com/smart-phone-flash-tool), or the Recovery alone. Just find a custom Recovery for your phone. // Also, CWM is a custom Recovery while Cyanogenmod is a custom ROM.

Comment: I didn't think to look for chipset information - thanks. Just to clarify, by finding a custom Recovery that will allow me to flash a custom ROM?

Comment: Yeah, you can flash a custom ROM easily through a custom Recovery. In fact, that's how most of the folks flash a custom ROM. I'm short on time to search, otherwise I would've mentioned a link of a custom Recovery for your device.

Answer (score -1):

I used kingroot to root my orion pro. Haven't found a custom recovery or ROM Yet. I used kingroot V 4.5.0.1 it roots your phone automatically by finding weaknesses and exploiting them. I'm also working on finding/making a custom recovery for the x500a.

Comment: Please explain the procedure you used to root the device. As of now, your answer is low-quality. Also, see [answer].