# Create a custom recovery from scratch

Tags: root-access, fastboot, android-sdk

I have an obscure Android phone (Orion Pro x500a). I have [another question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112412/is-rooting-possible-regardless-of-phone-model) which led me to ask another concerning custom recovery files.

Since my phone is rather obscure, I can't find a custom recovery file for it anywhere. I've looked into things like ROM Manager from CWM as well as other tutorials, but none give examples of the process used to create that custom recovery file.

Is there a way I can do that myself using something like the Android SDK or flashboot? Or, is the recovery based on the chipset of the phone and can I simply find a compatible recovery file based on that?

Comment: Did you try [this link](http://www.theandroidhow.com/2014/05/how-to-make-flash-cwm-recovery-without.html)? It  claims to make custom Recovery for most of the Mediatek devices and do that using **MTK Droid Root and Tools** and **SP Flash Tools** in combination.

Comment: Yeah, I came across that one. Working on a Mac, though, so I need to find an alternative.